# Is XmlRootAttribute inheritable?

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, xmlserializer

I have a class I am serializing with C#'s [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). It is marked with the [XmlRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) attribute, and I would like to inherit this attribute in a derived class.

Looking at the documentation it does not say that XmlRoot sets Inherit to false with AttributeUsageAttribute (Inherit is supposed to default to true), but I get an error when trying to deserialize my inherited class without an XmlRoot attribute ("<rootNode xmlns=''> was not expected.").

This currently works:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("rootNode")]
public class BaseClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("attributeA")]
    public int A { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("rootNode")]
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    [XmlElement("elementB")]
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work, but is what I want:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("rootNode")]
public class BaseClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("attributeA")]
    public int A { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    [XmlElement("elementB")]
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

The XML I might try to deserialize as a `InheritedClass` looks like this:

```
<rootNode attributeA="abc">
    <elementB>123</elementB>
</rootNode>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `Inherited` propertly merely indicates that the attribute **can** be inherited, not that it **will** be.  For example, if you look at the type signature for `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`, which is the most common way to retrieve these attributes, it has this overload:

```
public abstract Object[] GetCustomAttributes(bool inherit)
```

If the parameter `inherit` is `true`, then the method will search the inheritance chain, i.e. it will look to see if the base class or any ancestor classes have the attribute, if the specific type being looked at does not.  In order for this method to find an attribute on an inherited class, the attribute class itself must not set `AttributeUsage.Inherited = false`.

However, if the attribute's `AttributeUsage.Inherited` is `true`, the `GetCustomAttributes` method **will still ignore it if the `inherit` parameter is `false`.**

In other words, `AttributeUsage.Inherited` is a *permission*, not a *requirement*.  It is completely up to whomever invokes `GetCustomAttributes` (or a similar method) to decide whether or not to obtain inherited attributes.  You can't control this.  I'm fairly certain (not 100% positive) that the `XmlSerializer` does not look for inherited attributes.

Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but there you are; looks like you've already figured out the workaround.

Incidentally, the way it works with XML serialization is that the `XmlSerializer` uses the `XmlReflectionImporter` which in turn gets an instance of `XmlAttributes`.  Here is what the constructor looks like for `XmlAttributes` (out of Reflector):

```
public XmlAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
{
    this.xmlElements = new XmlElementAttributes();
    this.xmlArrayItems = new XmlArrayItemAttributes();
    this.xmlAnyElements = new XmlAnyElementAttributes();
    object[] customAttributes = provider.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    ...
}
```

So you can see that it does in fact pass **false** to the `GetCustomAttributes` method; it does *not* look for attributes in base classes, even if those attributes are "inheritable."

Comment: Thorough response, I appreciate the background. Thanks!

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for either, but at least a definitive answer. Thank you for the thorough explanation.