# How to serialise with custom namespace

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-serialization

I am serialising an object to XML and I get the output like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOrd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

However I would like it to be like so :

```
<SOrd xmlns:SOrd="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://....xsd">
```

**How can I do this?**

I have tried adding attributes to the root object before serialisation and also this :

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlNameSpace.Add("xmlns:SOrd", "http://...");
xmlNameSpace.Add("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://....xsd");

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(ord.GetType());
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath, false);
xs.Serialize(writer, ord, xmlNameSpace);
writer.Close();
```

But I get the exception **"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the prefic can't contain the ":", take out the first part xmlns:

here is your code slighly changed:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlNameSpace.Add("SOrd", "http://...");
xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlNameSpace.Add("schemaLocation", "http://....xsd");

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(ord.GetType());
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath, false);
xs.Serialize(writer, ord, xmlNameSpace);
writer.Close();
```

make sure to add the required attributes for each class since the serialization attributes are not inhereted. for more about the inheretence of attributes check: [How to deserialize concrete implementation of abstract class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743623/how-to-deserialize-concrete-implementation-of-abstract-class-from-xml/17744287#17744287)

**EDIT**

you can achieve the xsi:shcemaLocation Like that:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooData", Namespace = "http://foo.bar", DataType = "schemaLocation")]  
  public class Foo
  {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string schemaLocation = "http://example";
  }
```

Comment: I just did this before I read your message and it works, but the schemaLocation needs to have a prefix of xsi: how do I acheieve this?

Comment: Thanks it works :) one last thing is it possible to order the schema defs in a certail way? They seem to mixed around when output

Comment: I don't think it is possible, or at least I don't know of such a way. exept if you create your document using XmlWriter.