# IXmlSerializable abstract class creation exception

Tags: c#, mono, xml-serialization, xamarin, ixmlserializable

I am trying to serialize a series of subclasses deriving from a single abstract superclass `WorldObject` to XML, using the `IXmlSerializable` interface. I have to use this interface, as I want the class to subscribe to some events as it is deserializing.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590711/1422601) answer, I came up with the following code:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubType1))
,XmlInclude(typeof(SubType2))] // etc, includes all subtypes
public abstract class WorldObject : IComparable, IXmlSerializable

public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
{
    Type[] extraTypes = new Type[8];
    // (...) adding types to array here
    var worldObjectSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<WorldObject>), extraTypes);
}
```

The last line where the `XmlSerializer` is initialized throws a runtime error: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class 'Namespace.WorldObject'. The same error is thrown when I try to use `typeof(WorldObject)` instead of `typeof(List<WorldObject>)`.

I have also tried setting the XMLRoot to the same value in every class as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17744287/1422601), but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a way to get rid of the exception, but I found a workaround. The solution simply writes its own element wrapper with the type as its name, calls the WriteXml function and writes the end element.

```
foreach (WorldObject wO in list)
        {
             writer.WriteStartElement(wO.GetType().ToString());

             wO.WriteXml(writer);

             writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

This allows you to deserialize the concrete implementation of the abstract class as well. The `wO.GetType().ToString()` creates a string with the concrete class and namespaces. Then you can create an `XmlSerializer` where the type is gleaned from the element wrapper name, like so:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(reader.LocalName);
XmlSerializer worldObjectSerializer = new XmlSerializer(t, new XmlRootAttribute(reader.LocalName));
```