# Deserialize xml. xmlns='http//someaddress' was not expected

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-namespaces, xml-deserialization

My problem is with deserialization of xml to c# objects. I have some class derived from some other class (I have the reason why I need to use inheritance in this place - doesn't matter why):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName = "OTA_HotelResRQ")]
public class ResRQ : OTA_HotelResRQ
{
}
```

in OTA_HotelResRQ I have declared namespaces and other information:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", IsNullable = false)]
public class OTA_HotelResRQ : OtaRequestMessage, IRequest
```

And when I'm trying to serialize some request which looks like below:

```
<ns:OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" 
                PrimaryLangID="en" EchoToken="5613971064477293649" ResStatus="Commit" Version="2.1">
...SOME REQUEST WITH NS:....
<ns:POS><ns:/POS>
```

And now when I'm trying to deserialize this I have:

```
There is an error in XML document (3, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns='http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'> was not expected.
```

do you have some idea why I can't deserialize this? I can't modify base class for my model and also I need to have "ns" prefixes because service where I want to send that requires this format.

UPDATE:

My deserialization is implemented, that I'm getting bytes from string and try to deserialize using:

```
return (T) new XmlSerializer(typeof (T)).Deserialize(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

I tried to fix it using solution provided by Charles and I updated my model:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("OTA_HotelResRQ", Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
[XmlType("OTA_HotelResRQ", Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
public class ResRQ : OTA_HotelResRQ
{
}
```

but still with no success. When I try to deserialize then I'm getting exception:

```
Types 'OTA_HotelResRQ' and
 'ResRQ' both use the XML type name, 
'OTA_HotelResRQ', from namespace 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'. Use 
XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.
```

Comment: "I need to have "ns" prefixes because service where I want to send that requires this format" - unless the service has been very poorly written, no you don't. Namespace prefixes are local to a particular XML document. The two pieces of XML `<a:thing xmlns:a="http://example.com"/>` and `<b:thing xmlns:b="http://example.com"/>` *should* be treated identically. (As should `<thing xmlns="http://example.com"/>`)

Comment: not poorly, it was requirement to have prefixes

Comment: Yes, poorly, if it relies on *specific* prefixes. As I said, prefixes should only have meaning locally. What matters is the namespace itself (all three examples in my previous comment were a `thing` element from the `http://example.com` namespace)

Comment: ok doesn't matter that poorly or not. I can remove this derived class but still I have the same error that OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns='http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'> was not expected

Comment: ok I changed type name and then there was a problem. Now it's working, and I'm able to create and deserialize request with ns prefixes. I don't know how to do that with derived class but this is no longer required in this case. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

XML attributes [are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076024/is-xmlrootattribute-inheritable), so you need to add an `XmlRoot` attribute to your derived class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("OTA_HotelResRQ", Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
public class ResRQ : OTA_HotelResRQ
{
}
```

Comment: You'd need to add enough information to your question to reproduce your error.  A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).